# Is there anything wrong with way I am using django-smart-selects? Why am I not able to make a ModelForm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using django-smart-select. I want a form for my Location model which allows selection of continent based on which the Country will appear. After supplying the users address, the form needs to be submitted. This is what I have done.

```
 # myapp/models.py
 from django.db import models
 from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


class Continent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Country(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Location(models.Model):
newcontinent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
newcountry = ChainedForeignKey(
    Country, # the model where you're populating your countries from
    chained_field="newcontinent", # the field on your own model that this field links to
    chained_model_field="continent", # the field on Country that corresponds to newcontinent
   # show_all=False, # only shows the countries that correspond to the selected continent in newcontinent
)

my_address = models.CharField(max_length=20)


#myapp/forms.py
from myapp.models import Location
from django.forms import ModelForm

class LocationForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Location
    fields = ['newcontinent', 'newcountry', 'my_address']


#myapp/templates/myapp/addLocationForm.html   
{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Add a new location{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
 <button type="submit"> Post </button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}

#myapp/views.py
def addlocation(request):
if request.POST == "POST":
    form = LocationForm()
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('home')
else:
    form = LocationForm()
    return render(request, 'myapp/addLocationForm.html', { 'form': form})


#urls.py
 url(r'^location/add/$', core_views.addlocation,name='add-location'),
```

The above code does not work. I am able to select Continent added by admin. However, no option for selection of country appears.

I also tried using generic CreatView that didn't help and same result appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
Check in your admin page. If smart select works in the admin page then include  in your html file the following: The order matters.

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js</script>
        <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedm2m.js' %}"></script>
```